# PHP Add or Edit line in text File

Tags: php, file, replace, find, addition

I'm trying to search a text file, if a line contains a specific key  ID I want to update the entire line, if not add a new line.

So based on this text file :

```
admin,1234,ID1345,NW
staff,1325,ID1001,NE
staff,2157,ID2003,SW
staff,8519,ID3001,NS
```

I want to search for `ID1345` and then update that line only, the other lines stay exactly as they are.  If no lines contain `ID1345` then add a new line to the text file.

So far I've got:

```
$search = 'ID1345';
$result = 'admin,6698,ID1345,OP';

$reading = fopen('myfile', 'r');
$writing = fopen('myfile.tmp', 'w');
$replaced = false;

while (!feof($reading)) {
  $line = fgets($reading);
  if (stristr($line, $search)) {
    $line = "$result\n";
    $replaced = true;
  }
  fputs($writing, $line);
}

if (!$replaced) fputs($writing, "$result\n");
fclose($reading); fclose($writing);
rename('myfile.tmp', 'myfile');
```

This seems to work for the find and replace, but if the line doesn't exist it keeps adding it not just once.

I know this is due to the `if (!$replaced)` line, but I'm not sure how to do this.

The example above is small, but there could be a few thousand entries in the file..

Thanks

Comment: Side note: Is there a special/specific reason why you're not using a database for this? Text files are so much work.

Comment: Maybe the pointer is not at the right place. Test it. move the `if($repl..)` line under the `fclose()` and use `if($repl..) file_put_contents('myfile.tmp',"$result\n",FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: do you mean it keeps adding it when you run it just once this script, or only when you run several times using the same file? If the second case, maybe it could be the new line character which is not recognized? is is recommended on the manual to use `wb` instead of `w` with `fopen` for portability and new line chars..

Comment: @Fred-ii- unfortunately I don't have access to any databases on this system. Text file is all I have.

Answer (score 0):

```
function file_properties($fileProperties) {
$result = array();
$lines = split("\n", $fileProperties);
$key = "";
$isWaitingOtherLine = false;

foreach($lines as $i=>$line) {
    if(empty($line) || (!$isWaitingOtherLine && strpos($line,"#") === 0)) continue;

    if(!$isWaitingOtherLine) {
        $key = substr($line,0,strpos($line,'='));
        $value = substr($line,strpos($line,'=') + 1, strlen($line));
    } else {
        $value .= $line;
    }

    /* Check if ends with single '\' */
    if(strrpos($value,"\\") === strlen($value)-strlen("\\")) {
        $value = substr($value, 0, strlen($value)-1)."\n";
        $isWaitingOtherLine = true;
    } else {
        $isWaitingOtherLine = false;
    }

    $result[$key] = $value;
    unset($lines[$i]);
}

return $result;
```

}

This will read and write values to file with any extension like .env in Laravel or anything *.properties in Java